# How can I integrate a CSV-File into OMNeT++ latest Version?

Tags: c++, csv, omnet++

I use the Version 5.4.1 and Need to add a CSV-File that contains weather datas to OMNeT++ for simulating the Dataexchange between nodes. I do not know how I can add this file to OMNeT++ and could not find anything helpful in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OMNeT++ uses C++ to define behavior of modules, so one can use any available in C++ way to open a CSV file and parse it, for example look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c).
Moreover, OMNeT++ API contains [cStringTokenizer](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cStringTokenizer.html) class that may be used to parse a string.